# Compilation issue on mac Error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'wavenet::WaveNet'

Tags: c++, xcode, audio, deep-learning, plugins

I have a Compilation issue on mac, I'm trying to build this Neural Amp Modeler https://github.com/sdatkinson/iPlug2/tree/main/Examples/NAM on a Apple M1 MBP macOS 12.6 / Xcode 14.0

The code in that repository works on Windows but on my machine I get these errors:

```
Error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'wavenet::WaveNet'

In instantiation of function template specialization:

    'std::make_unique<wavenet::WaveNet, std::vector<wavenet::LayerArrayParams> &, 
const float &, const bool &, nlohmann::basic_json<>, std::vector<float> &>'

In file included from /Users/username/Dev/iPlug2/Examples/NAM/get_dsp.cpp

note: wavenet.h note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 4th argument
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 5 were provided
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 5 were provided'
```

I don't understand why it works on windows, I can post more code if need it and all the files are on the repository, Thanks!

Comment: `note: wavenet.h note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 4th argument` is the key error. How do you call this? I'm guessing with a rvalue? Looking at the code it does - change this line: `nlohmann::json& parametric,` to take it by const ref instead.

Comment: (Also it works on windows due to an extension in MSVC which can bind a rvalue to a _non const_ ref which is ugly).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, my current knowledge of C++ is not enough to try this idea.

Comment: It is [this line](https://github.com/sdatkinson/iPlug2/blob/main/Examples/NAM/wavenet.h#L206), plus line 230 in the same file, along with lines 253 and 326 in [wavenet.cpp](https://github.com/sdatkinson/iPlug2/blob/main/Examples/NAM/wavenet.cpp). Change the occurrences of `nlohmann::json&` to `nlohmann::json const&`. You could file it as a bug, it's actually invalid C++ that likely escaped attention due to MSVC, as @MikeVine suggested.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for the specific instructions, I'll try them later today!

Comment: I did the changes that @sigma and @Mike Vine suggested, I get these errors:<br/>
`Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'nlohmann::detail::iter_impl<nlohmann::basic_json<>>::pointer' (aka 'nlohmann::basic_json<> *') 
with an lvalue of type 'const nlohmann::detail::iter_impl<const nlohmann::basic_json<>>::pointer' (aka 'const nlohmann::basic_json<> *const')<br/>

1. in file included from wavenet.cpp:6:<br/>

2. in file included from wavenet.h:7:<br/>

3. In instantiation of member function 'nlohmann::detail::iter_impl<nlohmann::basic_json<>>::iter_impl' requested here`

Comment: Oh dear, that is a violation of "const correctness". I'll have to take a closer look through an IDE to see how problematic that is.

Comment: I happen to have the same type of MacBook and tried to compile the examples, but there was no end to the build errors... I'm guessing it really needs python 2.7 instead of 3 and you got it to work that way?

Comment: Forked my working configuration on macOS to https://github.com/ncsolar/iPlug2/tree/main/Examples/NAM It is building but I'm not able to make the app produce sound, I just get noise some kind of oscillation, maybe you will able to make it work! Feel free to contact me on GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick guess based on my experiences (Unfortunately, I cannot test it on a Mac).

Since the compile error comes from get_dsp.cpp we should try to fix it there before trying to change something in the class WaveNet itself.

The make_unique call is issued in get_dsp.cpp, line 83.

In line 87 is the 4th parameter to the constructor:

```
architecture == "CatWaveNet" ? config["parametric"] : nlohmann::json{}
```

I guess the default constructed nlohmann::json after the : is the root source of the compile error. This creates an un-named temporary object which is an rvalue.
But the constructor requires an lvalue (non-const reference to a nlohmann::json).
To fix that we must ensure we pass something which can act as an lvalue, so we need a named object, like this:

```
auto my_json = architecture == "CatWaveNet" ? config["parametric"] : nlohmann::json{};
```

This must be placed before the return statement in line 82 and then use "my_json" as constructor parameter in line 87.
The complete changed block will then look like this:

```
auto my_json = architecture == "CatWaveNet" ? config["parametric"] : nlohmann::json{};
return std::make_unique<wavenet::WaveNet>(
  layer_array_params,
  head_scale,
  with_head,
  my_json,
  params
);
```

Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, this is way beyond me.  Sadly I still get the same error after making the suggested changes, in Xcode if i click the error `Cannot initialize a member... ` I takes me to file json.hpp Line 9435 `: m_object(other.m_object), m_it(other.m_it)`

Comment: Is it the very same error? Did you fully revert all changes from your previous tries?

Unfortunately I dont know which variant / version of json.hpp is in use. 
Do you have an online link to the used file? 
What is the exact error message?

Comment: What I mean is, did you revert / undo all changes from WaveNet.h / WaveNet.cpp which were suggested in the other comments above ? 
It must be reverted before trying my approach.

Comment: It works now! I had to go and revert the previous changes and now the app builds! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @NC_DEV: Glad to hear that! :) I am happy that I could help with my guess. Thank you for marking my answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

So, just out of curiosity I did eventually get the MacBook to start compiling and reproduce your error. I'm not very familiar with MacOS at all, it is the system chosen by my new employer.

There is additional stuff in need of some TLC: python 2.7 is deprecated, and I'm sure you discovered as well that `std::exception("message")` is another [non-standard implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) provided by Microsoft.

However, I can now safely say that this really was the last non-portable code in this particular project, and that the `nlohman::json` parameter can be made a reference to const with one more change. To get rid of the last error you mentioned, modify [line 328](https://github.com/sdatkinson/iPlug2/blob/main/Examples/NAM/wavenet.cpp#L328)

```
  for (nlohmann::json::iterator it = parametric.begin(); it != parametric.end(); ++it)
```

to

```
  for (auto it = parametric.begin(); it != parametric.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I still had the same error, I'm sure I'm missing something.